# How do I get VLC Player or GNOME MPlayer to run DVDs I put into my computer?

Tags: lubuntu

I am using Lubuntu 13.04, I installed Lubuntu restricted extras back when I installed it, and It still didn't work? I put in a few choices of DVDs, She's the Man, Wreck it Ralph, etc. If I do get this fixed, will I be able to play bluray DVDs? I was able to on Xubuntu. It could be due to my CD Drive, or DVD drive not picking up on Lubuntu. I'm not sure.. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to download Ubuntu-restricted-extras from apt-get or from the software centre.

Answer (score 0):

Look here

System settings > Details > **Removable Media**

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+D or Media>play disk. I use a disk player on my raspi without restricted-extras and it works.(as long as ubuntu can see the disk)